# What is the official EASA definition of A, B, C and D checks, or where do I find it?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, easa-regulations

Schedule Maintenance is divided into many different checks. What is the official definition (EASA website, not wikipedia) of A, B, C and D check, or where do I find it?

Comment: I edited the question slightly to focus more on what the definition actually is, and less on where to find it. Feel free to [Edit] further, or to roll back, if you disagree.

Comment: Seems like no official definition. Just a grouping of required maintenance items put together in a schedule that change with airlines.